# Model appears incorrectly when I turn the view

Tags: 3d-view

When the view is right in front, it looks fine:
[image]

But when looking at from the side, it becomes abnormal:
[image]

Comment: Could you share your file on  https://blend-exchange.com/  ? This could be a number of things,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set different Blend Mode in the material properties:

[image]